# How to dynamically create Collapse component and pass parameter do Collapse Body on React native based on JSON response

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm having a problem that it's giving some headache, I have a **Collapse** component, that have a **Collapse Header** which is built based on the return of a **JSON** 
(that have an
 `id": 2,"categorY_DESCRIPTION": "CATEGORY NAME"`, this is working, i can get the response and build the component). And the **Collapse Body** of the **Collapse** should be based on the **Collapse Header** id parameter.
If someone can give a direction on how to achieve what I need, I'll appreciate a lot. I'll post my code bellow.

`const [auditItems, setAuditItems] = useState([]);
    const [auditCategory, setAuditCategory] = useState([]);
    const [checkListDesc, setcheckListDesc] = useState([]);`

//Here I get the categories which will be the Collapse Header

`useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://10.113.16.113:8081/api/auditcategory/getcategorybychecklist?checkListID="+checklistid, {

                    }).then
                    (function (response) {
                    setAuditCategory(response.data);
                    console.log(response.data);

                    }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);

                    })
    },[]);`

//Here I get items that will be in the Collapse Body

`useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://10.113.16.113/api/audititem/find?checklistid="+checklistid+"&catid="{categID}, {

                        }).then
                        (function (response) {
                            setAuditItems(response.data);
                            console.log(response.data); 
                        }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);

                        })
        },[]);`

This is how I'm building the component in the return()

```
{auditCategory.map(r =>(            
            <Collapse>
                <CollapseHeader>
                 <View style={styles.collapHead}>
                 <Text style={styles.collapHeadInput}>{r.categorY_DESCRIPTION}</Text>
    </View>
    </CollapseHeader>                
                <CollapseBody>
                 <ScrollView horizontal={true}>{auditItems.map(r =>(
                            <AuditItem title={r.subcategorY_DESCRIPTION}od={r.od}></AuditItem>
                           ))}
                </ScrollView>
                </CollapseBody>
            </Collapse>

       ))}
```

What I don't know is how to get the ID from auditCategory.map to use to get the items related to the right category.

This how I solved:

```
 {auditCategory.map(r =>(

            <Collapse>

                <CollapseHeader key={r.id} >
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> {
                // console.log("TESTE:"+r.id) 
                axios.get("http://100.13.16.113/api/audititem/findbycategorycheckl?checklistid="+checklistid+"&categoryid="+r.id,{                        
                }).then
                (function (response){
                    setAuditItems(response.data);
                 //   console.log(response.data);      
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
                    }}>
                 <View style={styles.collapHead}>


                 <Text style={styles.collapHeadInput} >{r.categorY_DESCRIPTION} </Text>

                  </View> 
                  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </CollapseHeader>                
                <CollapseBody>
                 <ScrollView horizontal={true}>

                        {auditItems.map(r =>(
                            <AuditItem title={r.subcategorY_DESCRIPTION}  od={r.od}></AuditItem>
                           ))}

                </ScrollView>
                </CollapseBody>
            </Collapse>

       ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem on how to get the ID to make the request based on the Collapse Header key. I'll edit the original post with the solution, maybe it's not the best practice but it works. If someone find I better solution, please let me know.